# Videos won't play from network share

Tags: networking, video

Ubuntu 18.04

When I try to play mp4 video from a network (CIFS) share, using the default video player, it says the stream is in the wrong format.   If I copy the file to the local hard drive, it plays fine. VLC seems to be able to play the file from remote.

However, VLC also appears to have a problem when opening a network folder that contains a set of DVD files.  It plays for a while, but inevitably crashes partway though, I suspect at a file boundary between fob files.   Again, it works fine if I copy the entire DVD folder to the local hard drive.

This all used to work fine in Ubuntu 16.04

What am I missing?

Comment: i have the same problem on 18.04

Answer (score -1):

I found that it work with SMB1 on server
I set in `smb.conf`:

```
min protocol = SMB1
max protocol = SMB1
```

And it works fine.

Comment: interesting.   Well, the device is a Synology NAS, so I'm not sure that I can change it yet.